# express-validator conditional validation with if/else

Tags: express, express-validator

In an expressjs app, I have express-validator to validate form input. I have an order endpoint that I need to validate the fields provided but can't figure out how to do conditional validation.

The inputs has order info where if it is delivery, I'll validate address fields but if the order is pickup, I don't need to validate it.

Here is the data I receive when it is a pickup:

```
 },
  user: 'guest',
  ordertype: 'Instore-Pickup',
  streetnumber: '',
  streetname: '',
  town: '',
  zip: '',
  time: 'ASAP',
  datepick: '',
  timechoice: '',
  ordernotes: '',
  username: 'marco',
  userphone: '8884449999',
  useremail: 'marco@marco.com',
  totalfixed: 346,
  taxfixed: '0.21',
  carttotalprice: 3.25
}
```

and if it is a delivery, here is the : please notice the streetnumber/streetname/town/zip fields

```
 },
  user: 'guest',
  ordertype: 'Delivery',
  streetnumber: '33 main street',
  streetname: 'A',
  town: 'union',
  zip: '07083',
  time: 'ASAP',
  datepick: '',
  timechoice: '',
  ordernotes: '',
  username: 'marco',
  userphone: '8884449999',
  useremail: 'marco@marco.com',
  totalfixed: 346,
  taxfixed: '0.21',
  carttotalprice: 3.25
}
```

I have this code:

```
var GuestValidate = [
    check("username").isLength({min : 3}),
    check('useremail', 'email must be an email').isEmail().normalizeEmail(),
     
 ];
```

and I use it inside my handle like so:

```
app.post('/guestorder', GuestValidate ,(req, res) => {

    const GuestValidationResults = validationResult(req);
    
    if (GuestValidationResults.isEmpty()) {
      //all handle code goes here.
      console.log("validation with no error")          
    }else{
      console.log("Error Validation")
      console.log("validation error -------- : ",GuestValidationResults.array())
    }
})
```

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
if(ordertype === "delivery"){
   //validate address + username, useremail, phonenumber
} else {
   // validate username, useremail, phonenumber (no address validation here)
}
```

I read the documentation and find oneOf()    [HERE](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/check-api) but not sure if it is the right way to do it or how to create oneOf() with ordertype === delivery if not ordertype === pickup?

Should I create 2 oneOf
onOf([checkaddressfield  +  username + useremail + phonenumber]),
onOff([check username + useremail + phonenumber])

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `custom` validator and check on the `ordertype`:

```
var GuestValidate = [
  check('ordertype')
    .custom((value, { req }) => {
        switch (value) {
          case 'delivery':
            // Validate req.body.address
            // If wrong address: throw new Error('Invalid address')
            break;
          case 'pickup':
            // Validate for pickup orders
            break;
          default:
            return true;
        }
    })
];
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. Where to validate without address fields if the order type is pickup?

Comment: @Marco In that case, you could validate on `ordertype` (check edited answer)

Comment: Thanks again. The solution you provided always producing an error after validating no matter the inputs value. I updated my question with fields and value I receive from the user so you can see what the data is.

Comment: @Marco If you pass a capped `ordertype` you should switch accordingly (`case 'Delivery'`)

Comment: I appreciate your help. What is capped ordertype means?